# Looking for Haskell `group` alternative in F#

Tags: f#

Haskell `group` descripted there: [http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:group](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3agroup)

example :

```
group "Mississippi" = ["M","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"]
```

Is there simple F# way of doing it?

I can implement something alike

```
let rec sameCounter (data : list<float>) el same (ss : list<float * int>) = 
    if data.Length > (el + 1) then
        if data.[el] = data.[el + 1] then
                              sameCounter data (el + 1) <| same + 1  <| ss
        else if same > 0 then sameCounter data (el + 1) <| 0         <| (data.[el], same) :: ss
             else             sameCounter data (el + 1) <| 0         <| ss
    else ss
let group d = sameCounter d 0 0 []
```

but it's a bit ugly way I think, is there better variant?

Comment: As far as I know there's no built in function for this, but you could implement it using Seq.fold instead.

Comment: @SimonDickson yes, I think it could be much better with fold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I came up with, I think it's reasonable:

```ml
let groupConsecutive sq =
    (Array.ofSeq sq, [])
    ||> Array.foldBack (fun x -> function
        | [] -> [[x]]
        | xs :: xss ->
            if x = List.head xs then
                (x :: xs) :: xss
            else [x] :: xs :: xss)
// val groupConsecutive : s:seq<'a> -> 'a list list when 'a : equality

groupConsecutive "Mississippi"
// val it : char list list = [['M']; ['i']; ['s'; 's']; ['i']; ['s'; 's']; ['i']; ['p'; 'p']; ['i']]
```

If you also want to be able to take and return infinite sequences, you'll need to work by hand with `GetEnumerator` and it gets much uglier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lazy version.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let groupConsecutive (sq : seq<_>) =
    let rec group (e : IEnumerator<_>) xs =
        seq {
            if e.MoveNext() then
                if e.Current = List.head xs then
                    yield! group e (e.Current :: xs)
                else
                    yield List.rev xs
                    yield! group e [e.Current]
            else
                yield List.rev xs
        }

    seq {
        let e = sq.GetEnumerator()
        if e.MoveNext() then
            yield! group e [e.Current]
    }
```

Comment: Nice. The only problem here is that this is not "stable": the elements in a bucket are in the reverse order compared to the original sequence. This might or might not matter depending on the application.

Comment: @Tarmil The order can be fixed, `|> Seq.map List.rev`. Then there's the inconvenient restriction on non-generic `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Why use non-generic `IEnumerator` in the first place by the way? It looks like this should work just fine with `IEnumerator<'T>`.

Comment: Updated answer to use generic IEnumerator and to return a stable answer.

Comment: `type seq<'T> = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>`

Comment: In [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) there is a generic function [chunkBy](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/bb60400df656bf848a0de2d4503783b4b034b773/src/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L329) which for sequences is lazy, so ``group`` will be ``chunkBy id >> map snd``.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with lists and pattern matching?

```
let group s =
    let rec loop = function  
        | x::xs, [] -> loop (xs, [x])                      // First element
        | x::xs, s::ss when x = s -> loop (xs, s::s::ss)   // Same
        | x::xs, ss -> ss :: loop (xs, [x])                // Different
        | [], ss -> [ss]                                   // Terminate
    loop (List.ofSeq s, [])

group "Mississippi"
```

This won't win any prizes for efficiency, but it is (reasonably) clear.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here's a fairly literal translation of the original haskell source implementation in terms of [span](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-List.html#span) and [groupBy](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#groupBy). With the proviso that a continuation `k` is needed to ensure tail-recursiveness.

```
let span p = 
    let rec loop k = function
    | x :: xs' when p x ->
        let f (ys, zs) = x :: ys, zs
        loop (f >> k) xs'
    | xs -> k ([], xs)
    loop id

let groupBy eq = 
    let rec loop k = function
    | [] -> k []
    | x :: xs ->
        let (ys, zs) = span (eq x) xs
        let f zss = (x :: ys) :: zss
        loop (f >> k) zs
    loop id

//Special case of 'groupBy', group by equality.
let group xs = groupBy (=) xs

group <| List.ofSeq "Mississippi" 
// val it : char list list =
//   [['M']; ['i']; ['s'; 's']; ['i']; ['s'; 's']; ['i']; ['p'; 'p']; ['i']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps:

[Seq.groupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)

> Applies a key-generating function to each element of a sequence and yields a sequence of unique keys and a sequence of all elements that have each key.

Note: `group` in Haskell is simply [`groupBy (==)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#group)

Comment: It's not the same: the Haskell one only groups successive equal values, while the F# one groups all equal values. `Seq.groupBy (=) "Mississippi" ≈ [('M', "M"); ('i', "iiii"); ('s', "ssss"); ('p', "pp")]`